# is there any way to write TCP server socket in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I have to write one Samsung smart TV application which consists of TCP server socket which will be listening to a certain port and whenever any event occurs, client will send event to the specific port to the server IP. I am using Javascript for writing server code but couldn't find any better way to write TCP server socket in Javascript.

Use case would be :

1. Client will be some device which will have server IP and port no registered with it.
2. when Client detects any event, it will send to the port .
3. Server will be our application which will written completely on Javascript,html and css.
4. Server will have TCP socket bind to the port where client will send the event so it should be able to receive the event and after processing the event , socket will again be on listening mode for another events.

Please help me to resolve this problem with proper code examples.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you cannot directly open a TCP port on the TV. However, it does support setup of REST APIs using the "[Convergence App API](http://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/files/guide/data/html/html_3/api_reference/javascript_apis/convergence_app_api/convergence_app.html)"

This way you can make simple HTTP calls to the server (If you have TCP available, HTTP is trivial)

Comment: Thanks for your input, but using convergence App api, I need to write the app in both sides means on device side as well as on Smart TV side but I don't have any hold on Client h/w device, it has only exposed some of the web services method using which we can configure the device and thereafter whenever device detects any events , it will send events to the configured port(may be internally it is using some web sevice call to send events).

Comment: In that case... I think you may struggle without some sort of intermediary service in the middle to convert your TCP calls to HTTP calls. The exception to this is if the event sent is using an HTTP format, in which case it may be possible to configure a widget on the TV in the correct location to receive the event. Perhaps an application like WireShark can help you to check the message format.

Comment: Thank You sir for clarifying the things.I would like to know more on if device send events in HTTP then what are the things we have to consider in my Smart TV app to receive the HTTP calls. If possible then please share me some sample application. Thanks once again.

Comment: I'm sorry... I don't have a sample I can share with you :( But I would be happy to have a look at WireShark output and try to help you get setup :D